# I created a foreign key constraint with update cascade but it does not update child table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Parent table

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.TBEMPLOYEE

2|Sohail Ashraf|1980-01-12 00:00:00.000|2013-12-05 15:40:48.303|Sen.Software Engineer|
```

Child table

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.TBADDRESS

2|Sohail Ashraf|sohail.azfal@netsoltech.com|923334447777gulberg|Lahore|Pakistan
```

Where `2` is the `emp_id` (PK) in parent table and FK in child table

When I update parent table like this

```
UPDATE TBEMPLOYEE
set emp_nme = 'Mohammad Sohail Ashraf'
WHERE emp_id = 2
```

Here is the result

```
2|Mohammad Sohail Ashraf|1980-01-12 00:00:00.000|2013-12-05 15:40:48.303|Sen.Software Engineer
```

but is does not update child table record.

Child table same as it above after update of parent table. Child table result like this

```
2|Sohail Ashraf|sohail.azfal@netsoltech.com|923334447777|gulberg|Lahore|Pakistan
```

Can anyone help me ?

Comment: Your schema seems redundant. Foreign Key constraints are meant to reduce redundancy by storing the data in one table and fetching it via the key. Here, you have the name in two tables.

Answer (score 3):

You misunderstand what that cascade means.  It only applies to the foreign key column(s), not the whole record.  If you change the value in the PK field in the parent record then the new value will cascade to the FK field in the child record(s).  No other fields are affected.

That begs the question, why do you have data duplicated in the first place?  If you have the name stored in the parent record then why do you have it in the child record as well?  It should only be in one or the other.  If you need data from both tables then you perform a join.

Answer (score 2):

A cascade update updates the foreign key in the child table when the primary key in the parent table is updated.